# Royalslider dynamic change scalemode and video container

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with Royalslider. I am trying to change the scalemode for each slide with this code:

```
<div class="royalSlider rsDefault">
<img class="rsImg" scale="fill" data-rsVideo="1496.mp4" src="test.jpg" alt="image description" />
<img class="rsImg" scale="fit-if-smaller" src="test.jpg" alt="image description" />
<img class="rsImg" scale="fit" src="test.jpg" alt="image description" />
</div>
```

Then I use the build in function to get the attr *"scale"* with this:

```
imageScaleMode: function(slideObject) { 
return slideObject.content.attr('scale'); },
```

All of this works fine.

The problem is when I try to use video. Then Royalslider adds a container *(with the class ".rsVideoContainer")* around the image and then it can't read the attr *"scale"*

How can I target the image attr inside the video container?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem with this code:

```
return slideObject.holder.find('.rsImg').attr('scale');
```